# Google Analytics support for the amp-pixel tag

Tags: analytics, amp-html

The tag amp-pixel is used to count the page views.

Is there a way to use it with Google Analytics?

The [GitHub page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-pixel.md) does not show any implementation.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: Use [amp-analytics](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/amp-analytics.md) component.

<strike>I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mika-/90336cc3780c2a891da7) about this some time ago.</strike>

```
<amp-pixel src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;tid=UA-12345678-1&amp;t=pageview&amp;cid=$RANDOM&amp;dt=$TITLE&amp;dl=$CANONICAL_URL&amp;z=$RANDOM"></amp-pixel>
```

AMP library provides almost all parameters needed for reasonable tracking. Only one missing is the `cid`, which is used to identify specific users. As you can't use extra javascript on AMP pages, you need to create and populate the identifier on server side.

For more information check the [Google Analytics protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the data is gathering now, we'll see how it's rendered in the Analytics interface.

Comment: Do you know how it should show in the Analytics interface?

Comment: Example doesn't make difference between normal and amp hits. To do that you could use [Custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_)

Comment: "populate the identifier on server side"  that is not-so-good idea. AMP is meant for static content and that would make your page dynamic. Caching would not work and it would slow your loading speed.

Comment: I've followed your implementation (the gist) and data is still not populating.. :( Are there any other criteria that have to be met in order for the amp-pixel to start recording data? (It fires and generates a 200)

Comment: How random should `$RANDOM` be?  We're targeting Google's AMP approach which is served from their cache & CDN, that means that `$RANDOM` will be the same for all users until the document is refreshed.  Do you see this causing a problem?